# undefined function onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to create a website that would get the user input, selected options and email those inputted information to the user's email. My problem here is the onClick event doesn't work properly, it does nothing and shows that the function is not defined.

```
        Name:<br><input type="text" id="name" required/> <br/>

                <label><br>Example</label> 
                <br>
                    <select name="choice">
                    <option value="" selected>--SELECT--</option>
                    <option value="choice1">choice1</option>
                    <option value="choice2">choice2</option>
                    
                   </select><br>
   
                <button type='submit' onclick='myFunction()'>SUBMIT</button>
```

The function that would supposedly get the data from user input upon clicking submit.

```
function myFunction(){

  var name = $("#name");
  var email = $("#email");
  var schedule = $("#schedule");
  var time = $("#time"); 


  if(isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(time) && isNotEmpty(schedule)) {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'send.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
           name: name.val(),
           email: email.val(),
           schedule: schedule.val(),
           time: time.val() 
        }, success: function(response){
           $("#status")[0].reset();
           $('.status').text("Kindly check your email for status of Delivery. Thank you!");
        }
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript != Java

Comment: Is the function defined at top-level in the JavaScript, or is it nested inside another function? `onclick` is executed in the global scope.

Comment: Where is your `myFunction` defined?  Is it in a doc.ready or other namespacing?  It must be declared globally to be visible by `onclick=`.  One of the (*many*) reasons people generally recommend against `onclick=`

Comment: Also note that your button is `type=submit` so if your inputs are in a form, you'll get the ajax send.php *and* the form post.

Comment: you are getting the element before checking if it is empty that seems wrong you should get the val first then check otherwise IDK what's wrong with the code.

Comment: also $("#status")[0] $(".status") might be a bug is it both a class and an id?

Comment: @Barmar it is my first function. yes it is defines at the top-level in the javascript

Comment: Are there any other errors in the console? What do you see if you type `console.log(myFunction)` in the console?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm sorry I don't know what you mean about doc.ready or namespacing because i'm new to this. I tried changing the type=submit to type=button , nothing happens.

Comment: @SolomonPByer thank you I didn't noticed that

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering, I just change the way i coded it. It's okay now and i just did not used the onclick event.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score -2):

Add **jquery** file to header. I think it's after the jquery code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This wouldn't cause that error. The error would say that `$` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering, I just change the way i coded it. It's okay now and i just did not used the onclick event